# How can I parse a json with colon in android?

Tags: android, json

I have a json with colon between the strings, and I'm not sure how can I parse it. I know that I don't have an array in the json, but I'm not sure how can I get the values...

```
{
    "config": {
        "network": {
            "hni:21407" : "num:[INTNUM]",
            "hni:311490" : "num:044[INTNUM]"
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I'm trying, but I never go through the loop for, and not really sure if I need it.

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(netWorkJson);
String arr = obj.optString("network");

for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    String hni = obj.getString("hni");
    String num = obj.getString("num");
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its kind of json object inside json objet

Comment: what problem you are facing?Json looks fine and so are the objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to parse the inner json object "network", after that you can loop over it's keys and get the values for them one by one:

```
private void parseJSON(String netWorkJson) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(netWorkJson);
    JSONObject config = obj.getJSONObject("config");
    JSONObject network = config.getJSONObject("network");

    Iterator<?> keys = network.keys();
    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) keys.next();
        String value = network.getString(key);
    }
}
```

Beauty of this is that it will also work if you had 100 hni values for example, and that you don't have to get them one by one.

Answer (score 0):

`network` is `JSONObject` instead of `JSONArray`, so no need to use for-loop for getting value from it.just use do it as:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(netWorkJson);
// get network JSONObject from obj

JSONObject network=obj.getJSONObject("network");

// get both values from network object
String strHni=network.optString("hni:21407");
String strNum =network.optString("hni:311490");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 JSONObject message = new JSONObject(config);
 String value=message.getJSONObject("network").getString("hni:21407")
```

Try This

Answer (score 0):

```
  try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("config");

        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("network");

        for(int i =0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){

            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

            String hni21407 = jsonObject1.getString("hni:21407");
            String hni311490 = jsonObject1.getString("hni:311490");

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```